# Using comma with "nevertheless"

Tags: sentence-structure, adverbs, commas

I just finished reading that [thread](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-sentences-using-the-word-nevertheless). I have some questions in my mind now.

1- As far as I understand by looking these examples, we don't really have to use comma or semicolon to connect two sentences when "nevertheless" is used. Am I right? (The examples are a,b,c)

> a) He was very tired; ***nevertheless*** he went on walking.
>
> b) She was very tired, ***nevertheless*** she kept on working.
>
> c) We are going ***nevertheless*** we shall return.

Isn't using "nevertheless" to combine two independent clauses without comma and semicolon considered wrong?

> I think we need to rephrase it "We are going; ***nevertheless***, we shall
>   return.

---

2- That use kind of puzzled me. (d) " Nevertheless" was used like "however". But most examples don't use comma before or after "nevertheless" unless it was used at the beginning of a sentence. For example, in the "e", there is no comma.

> d) What you said was true. It was, ***nevertheless***, a little unkind.
>
> e) The two rivals were ***nevertheless*** united by the freemasonry of the
>   acting profession.

So can I use this version of "d":

> What you said was true. It was ***nevertheless*** a little unkind.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that examples  a, b, and c should all use a semi colon. They could, after all, be recast as separate sentences. However, you will see such forms used with a comma or no punctuation at all rather often. Note that in each case "however" could be substituted for 'nevertheless" with little or no change of meaning.

In both examples d and e I would consider 'nevertheless a parenthetical expression, and use commas before and after it. And yes, here again "however" could be substituted for 'nevertheless" with little or no change of meaning.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help.